# Automatically warning when adding post containing greetings and signatures?

Tags: feature-request, signatures

Related to [Automatically flag posts containing a link to the same site as user's profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83451/automatically-flag-posts-containing-a-link-to-the-same-site-as-users-profile)

FAQs clearly discourage (or actually disallow) using signatures. Meta discussions seem to encourage removing greetings ("Hi", "I am new here" and so on), as well as end notes like "Cheers", "Best regards" an so on.

Why there is no automatic message saying "You should not sign your messages" and probably something to discourage unnecessary greetings in the beginning?

Similarly, subjective titles produce

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 10):

This could be done by looking for "Hi" or "Hello" at the beginning of the question and showing  a warning.  It would not catch everything, but it does have the potential to cut back on some of the greetings and signatures.

Comment: Yes, and similarly "cheers" and "regards" as last words in posts. (Including answers)

Comment: ^\s*[gG]ood immediately