# Proposal to generate automatic warning if salutation is detected in a post

Tags: feature-request, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically warning when adding post containing greetings and signatures?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83465/automatically-warning-when-adding-post-containing-greetings-and-signatures)

Dear all,

I think it would be a good idea to add automatic salutation detection for posts, similar to how it automatically detects subjective titles.

So if a post contains words like "hi", "hello", "dear", "sincerely", "thanks", a user would be presented with a warning message (a post still can be submitted).

Thanks and all the best wishes. Yours truly.

Comment: You sure have that down yourself :P Oh yeah, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your question!  It's users like you that make this site awesome.

Anyway, I agree with your request.  We already implement something similar for subjective words in the title.  I expect running a regex over the body won't hurt when they move to the tag box.

Thanks for the question, hope this helps!

-Adam

Comment: Hi Adam! I hope the beginning spring finds you in the best of forms. Did you know that your city is sister cities with my home town Tübingen? What a nice coincidence, don't you think. At first thought, I  disagreed with the suggestion - I think the current system tends to work well, and  anybody sticking on the site for a while will get the drift pretty quickly. But then I thought some more, and arrived at the conclusion that a detection and a polite *warning* can't hurt.  Anyway, have a great evening and a nice weekend! Sincerely, Pekka