# Automatic moderator flags for potential spammers

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically flag posts containing a link to the same site as user's profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83451/automatically-flag-posts-containing-a-link-to-the-same-site-as-users-profile)

The MO of a spammer is usually to link to the same domain they have registered in their user profile as e-mail or web site.

Is it possible to automatically flag these for moderators if e.g. at least 50% of their posts link to that domain?